# Wave functions of valence and conduction electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, physical-chemistry, wavefunction-collapse

I read that the standard depiction of covalent bonding is misleading. It gives the impression that the valence electron exists at that bond site. But really it exists as a wave throughout the crystal. So is it a standing wavefunction that has a peak at the bond site? From this can we infer that conduction electrons have propagating wavefunctions? Furthermore, how is it that an electron can mantain its wave characterictics in a crystal? We know that oberservations (more accurately interactions) collapse the wave function. Certainly the electron is interacting with many potentials and forces in a crystal.

Answer (score 0):

> It gives the impression that the valence electron exists at that bond site. But really it exists as a wave throughout the crystal.

Correct

> So is it a standing wavefunction that has a peak at the bond site?

No. Electron quasiparticles in a semiconductor are not associated with any particular atom or bond.

> From this can we infer that conduction electrons have propagating wavefunctions?

Yes

> Furthermore, how is it that an electron can mantain its wave characterictics in a crystal? We know that oberservations (more accurately interactions) collapse the wave function. Certainly the electron is interacting with many potentials and forces in a crystal.

You are looking for "Bloch's Theorem". Electron quasiparticles exist in states that are solutions to the Schrodinger equation in the presence of a periodic potential.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually already familiar with Bloch's theorem but couldn't see why my heuristic argument was wrong. Have you ever been in a state where you can follow to lines of reasoning that lead to different conclusions? Like you see both sides of the argument and don't know which one is correct? Bloch's theorem is definitely rigorous so I guess I just need to conlcude that I had the wrong idea of what causes a wave collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Too many questions in one post is not recommend, especially to get an accurate and specific answer. What matters are the expected properties before any measurement, we do not care about a collapse, it is a misunderstanding to think about the particle not the state.

A [covalent bond](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond) is a chemical thing, mostly for systems with localised orbitals (atoms and molecules). A clearer definition would be that a covalent bond is formed when there is an overlap between the orbitals, even if the orbitals don't overlap, there is a non-covalent electrostatic interaction between the particles occupying the states. This definition includes the fact that a covalent bond can be between more than two atoms, called a delocalised covalent bond, which is certainly misleading. That's why we don't care about covalency in solid state physics.

> It gives the impression that the valence electron exists at that bond site.

The word "electron" should be avoided, it leads to this confusion between the localised particle and the delocalised state. At this level of solving the Schroedinger equation, the state is more important, not really the particle, the particle is important after a measurement. Since the states overlap, they are present throughout the crystal. The time-independent solution gives standing waves. The difference between a conducting state or a non-conducting state is another matter, mainly related to the effect of the real operator position $\hat{x}$ (potential) compared to the complex operator momentum $\hat{p}$ and if another state is directly available after the highest occupied state. Under potentials the position $r$ will be more accurate and the momentum less accurate but the "wave function or the state remains" and does not collapse until a measurement is performed.